# MVC Controller Action returning html and not bool

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a controller action from a modal and display a message on the modal saying whether an update has been successful or not.

Should be easy eh? Not for me :)

For some reason, the result from the controller action is rendering in the browser instead of returning to my jquery, which I wanted to update the modal with...

I cannot work out why the "true" or "false" is returning to the browser and not the jquery?

Here is my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public bool Add(ViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            // update the achievement
            model.achievementItem.EventDate = DateTime.Now;
            model.achievementItem.StaffID = CurrentUser.StaffID;
            bool success = AddAchievement(GlobalVariables.networkstuff, GlobalVariables.testAuth, model.achievementItem);

            return success;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;

        }
    }
```

And this is my modal, with the javasctipt at the bottom.

At the moment I have only got as far as trying to put the response into the

```
    <div d="detailsDiv"></div>

Here is my partial view:

    @model Models.ViewModel
<div class="modal-body">
    <div>Add achievement for FirstName LastName</div>
    <hr />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Achievement", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "add" }))
    {
    <div>
        <div>Achievement Type (Required)</div>
        <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.achievementItem.BehaviourType, Model.achivementDetails.PositiveOutcomes.Select(d => new SelectListItem { Text = d.Description, Value = d.Code }), new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
        <div>Activity Type (Optional)</div>
        <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.achievementItem.Subject, Model.achivementDetails.EventSubjects.Select(d => new SelectListItem { Text = d.Description, Value = d.Code }), "", new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
        <div>Awared Given (Optional)</div>
        <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.achievementItem.PositiveOutcome, Model.achivementDetails.PositiveEventTypes.Select(d => new SelectListItem { Text = d.Description, Value = d.Code }), "", new { @class = "form-control" })</div>
        <div>@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.achievementItem.Comment, new { @class = "field span12" })</div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.achievementItem.StudentID, "1")
    </div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">
                    Cancel
                </button>
                <button type="submit" id="approve-btn"
                        class="btn btn-danger">
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="detailsDiv"></div>
    }
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#add').submit(function () { // catch the form's submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: $(this).attr('POST'), // GET or POST
                url: $(this).attr('add'), // the file to call
                success: function (response) { // on success..
                    $('#detailsDiv').html(response); // update the DIV
                }
            });
            return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone suggest why the Boolean is coming back to the browser and not returning to the javascript please?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

This is the code I have now based on suggestions but the json response is actually popping up in the browser as a file to download, not in the

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(ViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            // update the achievement
            model.achievementItem.EventDate = DateTime.Now;
            model.achievementItem.StaffID = CurrentUser.StaffID;
            bool success = SIMSClient.ClientFunctions.AddAchievement(GlobalVariables.networkstuff, GlobalVariables.testAuth, model.achievementItem);

            return Json(success);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(false);

        }
    }
```

Partial View / Modal JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#add').submit(function () { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Add")',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#detailsDiv').html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

ANOTHER UPDATE:

When I search for a controller returning json to the browser... i found this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/576198/ASP-NETplusMVCplus-plusJSONplusresponseplussendspl

I then changed my controller action to be:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Add(ViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            // update the achievement
            model.achievementItem.EventDate = DateTime.Now;
            model.achievementItem.StaffID = CurrentUser.StaffID;
            bool success = SIMSClient.ClientFunctions.AddAchievement(GlobalVariables.networkstuff, GlobalVariables.testAuth, model.achievementItem);

            //return Json(success);
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
            result.Data = success.ToString();
            result.ContentType = "text/plain";
            return result;

        }
        catch
        {
            //return Json(false);
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
            result.Data = "false";
            result.ContentType = "text/plain";
            return result;
        }
    }
```

and it still displays in the browser instead of the div in the partial modal...

stumped.

Comment: Your `Add` method should return be `public ActionResult Add()`, not `public bool Add()`, and you should return json from the method - `return Json(new { status = "true"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Comment: Or possibly just `return Json(success);`. Also no need for AllowGet as it is a post

Comment: Is your action method hit from JS at all?

Comment: yes. It does get hit... I have just updated my code with the above suggestions and I am now getting the complete "parent" page rendered in my <div> uh?

Comment: What is the exact response text that is returned in the response body (look in the console's net panel)?

Comment: I now get the response coming back as a json file to download... im stumped

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute POST of 'form'

try like following:

```
$('#add').submit(function () { // catch the form's submit event
        $.ajax({ 
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            type: 'POST', 
            url: '@Url.Action("Add")', 
            success: function (response) {
                $('#detailsDiv').html(response); 
            }
        });
        return false; 
    });
```

Update: 
this is quite simple. See the code below

```
 try
    {
        // update the achievement
        model.achievementItem.EventDate = DateTime.Now;
        model.achievementItem.StaffID = CurrentUser.StaffID;
        bool success = SIMSClient.ClientFunctions.AddAchievement(GlobalVariables.networkstuff, GlobalVariables.testAuth, model.achievementItem);

        if(success){
            return Json("true");
        }
        return Json("false");
    }
    catch
    {
        return Json("false");
    }
```

Comment: this helps - but now I get a popup at the bottom of the browser asking me if I want to download the .json file... weird

Answer (score 0):

the return value of the function should be ActionResult and the value returned as Content(success.ToString()):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(ViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        // update the achievement
        model.achievementItem.EventDate = DateTime.Now;
        model.achievementItem.StaffID = CurrentUser.StaffID;
        bool success = SIMSClient.ClientFunctions.AddAchievement(GlobalVariables.networkstuff, GlobalVariables.testAuth, model.achievementItem);

        return Content(success.ToString());
    }
    catch
    {
        return Content(false.ToString());;

    }
}
```

Comment: when I change my code to this I still get the true/false displayed in a browser and not on my modal :(